# Use QWaitCondition in a thread started by QtConcurrent

Tags: qt, qthread, qtconcurrent

i have a function that is started by a QTconcurrent run. Inside this function i use QThread (To get the Thread created by the QTConcurrent run) static method to sleep it for some time, but i don't want anymore to use time to activate it, i'd like to use a WaitCondition to wake the thread in another point of the execution, but i searched a lot and don't find any case like this. I only see WaitConditions inside run() methods. Is there some way to use QWaitCondition in a thread started by QtConcurrent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need a mutex:

```
void work(QMutex* mutex, QWaitCondtion* cond, volatile bool* wake){
    //do work
    {
        QMutexLocker locker(mutex);
        while(!*wake){
            cond->wait(mutex);
        }
    }
    //do more work
}
```

The loop is necessary to avoid spurious wakeups and let the thread fall through if `wake` is already set to `true`. Locking over the entire loop is needed to avoid various race conditions.

You wake the thread with:

```
{
    QMutexLocker locker(mutex);
    *wake = true;
    cond->wakeOne();
}
```